# Coding for Input/Output: Speed or Memory priority?

Tags: performance, memory, coding-style, io

I am currently writing a simple piece of IO parsing, and is in a dilemma as to how should I code it.

This is the case of a web application, where this particular parsing function may be called multiple times within a second by several users.

Assume that the file size is more than 2 MB and Hardware IO delays are 5ms for each call.

#### First Case: Memory

The first case would be to code for memory, but at the expense of speed. The function will take in small parts of the file and parse by the parts thus using more iterations, but less memory.

Pseudo-code:

```
function parser() {
    Open file and put into handle variable fHandle
    while (file position not passed EOF) {
        read 1024 bytes from file using fHandle into variable data
        process(data)
    }
    Close file using handle fHandle
}
```

#### Second Case: Speed

The second case would be to code for speed, at the expense of memory usage. The function will load the entire file content into memory and parse it directly.

Pseudo-code:

```
function parser() {
    read entire file and store into variable data
    declare parsing position variable and set to 0
    while (parsing position not past data length) {
        get position of next token and store into variable pos
        process( substring from current position to pos of data )
    }
}
```

Note: when reading entire file we are using library direct-available functions to read the entire file. No loops are used in reading the file on the developer's end.

#### Third Case: End-user choice

Would it then be advisable to write for both, and whenever the function runs, the function will detect whether memory is abundant or not. If there is a lot of free memory space, the function will use the memory-intensive version.

Pseudo-code:

```
function parser() {
    if (memory is too little) {
        Open file and put into handle variable fHandle
        while (file position not passed EOF) {
            read 1024 bytes from file using fHandle into variable data
            process(data)
        }
        Close file using handle fHandle
    } else {
        read entire file and store into variable data
        declare parsing position variable and set to 0
        while (parsing position not past data length) {
            get position of next token and store into variable pos
            process( substring from current position to pos of data )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How big are your files, on average?

Comment: I mentioned, assumption made is file size minimum is 2 MB. Well if you need an exact estimate then take 2 MB for each file.

Comment: I would just load it to RAM, as 2MB is nothing. But that's just me.

Comment: 2 MB is nothing for one user. 2 MB from 1000 users at the same time is something.

Comment: Ah, missed the multi-user part. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use asynchronous I/O (or a second thread), and process one chunk of data while the drive's busy fetching the next chunk.  Best of both worlds.

Comment: A single thread can use asynchronous I/O if the platform supports it.  If it's not supported, or if it's supported badly, then a second thread would effectively accomplish the same goal -- which is, to process and read at the same time as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read the full file either way and it fits into memory without issue, then read it from memory.  Will it be the same file every time, or some small set of files?  Cache them in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If the input for your parsing comes from I/O, as it usually does, any good parsing technology, like recursive-descent, will be I/O bound.
In other words, the average time to get a character from the I/O should exceed the average time spent processing it, by a healthy factor.
So it really doesn't matter very much.
The only difference will be in how much working storage you glom onto, which is not usually a big deal.

Comment: but how would the developer know the average times and compare it, since that is a variable depending on the system the application is deployed onto.

Comment: What I do is this. First, I test on a slow machine, so if it's not an issue there, it will be even less of an issue on a fast machine. If I have the slightest concern about it, I *[tune the code by this method](https://sourceforge.net/projects/randompausedemo/)*, to squeeze out any unnecessary cycles. Then if I still think it might be an issue, I might consider double-buffering, as cHao suggested, the object being to keep the I/O hardware busy as much as possible.